# homebrew with M1 macbook air error when starting terminals

Tags: homebrew, apple-m1

I installed homebrew 3.0.0 on my M1 MBA.

However, every session including iterm2 terminal and tmux shows this error message:

`/Users/jinrae/.zprofile:1: no such file or directory: opt/homebrew/bin/brew`

In my case, it does not harm functionality at least in my usage pattern.

Anyhow, how can I get rid of this message?

Comment: I would check the contents of the `.zprofile` file.  Homebrew is supposed to be installed at `/opt/homebrew/bin/brew`.  That path you are getting an error for is different (missing the leading `/`).  So it's probably not able to load that profile correctly.  Though your homebrew itself may be working correctly

Comment: @sedavidw I think that your idea is reasonable. In `.zprofile`, only a single line was written as `eval $(opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)`. I added `/` in front of `opt` but it does not resolve the issue.

Answer (score 20):

I got this error because I installed brew on the Rosetta version of terminal to install packages, that are not yet M1 compatible.

To get rid of this message i opened my `.zprofile` with `nano .zprofile`.

The first line was

> eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"

And i simply put a # before this line to comment it out and the message was gone.

Comment: This was correct for me. Brew doctor was telling me it should be reinstalled because it was in /opt? instead of local or something. When I reinstalled it still had the old .zprofile line and the new one so commenting it out fixed the problem.

Answer (score 9):

To @sedavidw, `/opt/homebrew/bin` contains `.keepme` without contents:

```
/Users/jinrae/.zprofile:1: no such file or directory: opt/homebrew/bin/brew
➜  bin pwd
/opt/homebrew/bin
➜  bin la
total 0
-rw-r--r--  1 jinrae  admin     0B Feb  9 11:04 .keepme
```

EDIT: I read an article saying that `homebrew` is installed in `/opt/homebrew/bin` in M1 Mac whereas it is installed in `/usr/local` in Intel Mac. I'm trying to reinstall homebrew for M1 Mac now.

EDIT2: I solved the problem. It was due to for what homebrew is installed. As I heard, homebrew is installed in `/usr/local` for Intel Mac and `/opt/homebrew/bin` for M1 Mac.

I reinstalled homebrew with

`/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://gist.githubusercontent.com/nrubin29/bea5aa83e8dfa91370fe83b62dad6dfa/raw/48f48f7fef21abb308e129a80b3214c2538fc611/homebrew_m1.sh)"`

which is slightly different from that in the official site (at least to me).
Anyhow, newly installed homebrew is located in `/opt/homebrew/bin` and the problem has been solved.

Answer (score 8):

If you are using an Intel Mac, as mentioned above, Homebrew gets installed on `/usr/local.` Therefore, modify your `.zprofile` file (located in `users/<username>`) to use the correct path. Here is content of `.zprofile`:

```
eval "$(/usr/local/Homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

Open your terminal and run following command

`sudo nano ~/.zprofile`

replace the `eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"` with `eval "$(/usr/local/bin/brew shellenv)"` and save.

Answer (score 0):

To Fix Type
`nano .zprofile`
then delete all of the stuff
then do `⌃X`
then press `return`

Answer (score 0):

I have the M1 Mac and it was installed in /opt/homebrew/...

I opened /Users/~username~/.zprofile and it had two lines.

First line was:

```
eval "$opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv"
```

Second like was:

```
eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"
```

I just commented out the first line which doesn't actually have the </opt/> in the address. It's asking for a $opt, and *then* the address. So commenting out that line removed the location error and just read the correct line. So it doesn't show the error anymore when opening the terminal.